# Ajax call send wrong data to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

With the script below I call an action method for managing the permission of users. On the first time everything works, but when I debug the controller my variable `grp` gets the value of `usr`.

My view code

```
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <br />
  <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
    @{
        int count = 1;
        //inizialize my ef context
        dev_labelsEntities db = new dev_labelsEntities();
        //get all users stored in the db
        var users = from u in db.Users
                    orderby u.username
                    select new
                    {
                        u.username
                    };
        //get all groups from the db
        var groups = from g in db.Groups
                     orderby g.group_name
                     select new
                     {
                         g.group_name
                     };
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            @foreach (var item in groups)
            {
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.group_name)</td>
            }
        </tr>
        foreach (var item in users)
        {


            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.username)</td>
                @foreach (var itemG in groups)
                {
                  //in the input tag i define the values which i want to get  
                  <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkclass" 
                   username="@item.username" groupname="@itemG.group_name" 
                   id="@count" />
                   count++;
                </td>
                }
            </tr>

           }
       }            
     </table>
   </div>
 </body>
```

This is my JQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chkclass').click(function() {
    var getchkid = $(this).attr('id');
    var isChecked = $('#' + getchkid).is(':checked');
    if ($('#' + getchkid).is(':checked') == true) {

      // to be send to your call
      var username = $(this).attr('username');
      var groupname = $(this).attr('groupname');

      //here put your call ajax to your action
      $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        url: '/UserGroups/ManagePermission',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          'usr': username,
          'grp': groupname
        },
        success: function(data) {},
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
          alert(thrownError);
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

The code in the controller is only for testing that everything works.

Does anyone have any idea why I get this behaviour?

EDIT

After get in the method without any operations
[image]

Here the for is complete and look at to the values of variables
[image]

EDIT 2

Here the values sent from the client

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. The JS seems fine, and then you're returning an error response from your MVC action in all conditions. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: What is the content of usr on your backend?

Comment: You should also include your form input data to your question.

Comment: @HirasawaYui i'll attach my view code

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The values of grp is wrong, because it has 'develop01' instead of 'Admin' for example

Comment: Ok, so where do those values come from? Your question doesn't show that. Have you also checked the request to ensure you're sending the correct data? You need to pinpoint the part of the code where the values change from what you expect them to be

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The values come from the input tag, check the view code

Comment: I can see that. My point is you need to check what the actual data is in the console when the request is sent to at least figure out if what is being sent is wrong, or if you're doing something wrong on the server side.

Comment: shouldn't the `count` variable be incremented inside the foreach for groups in the view code?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In the edit section i attach more info

Comment: @Matt.G yeah, fixed it look at the code now

Comment: @LeonardoBassi What is being sent from the client? Have you inspected the HTTP request using something like Wireshark or Fiddler, or have you tried to inspect what is being sent from the JavaScript?

Comment: The screenshots you keep posting are meaningless. Please actually check the values sent from the client.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the values sent by the client are correct, i attach the screenshot

Comment: Are you saying the value of grp is changing during that for loop?

Comment: If that's the case, are you running in release or debug mode?

Comment: @bgraham yes, the value of grp change after every kind of operation and i am in debug mode

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty bizarre. I bet its something wrong with your environment. Not to be cliche, but definitely try restarting your computer and visual studio if you haven't. One thing you could do is try returning Json(new { usr: usr, grp: grp }) and seeing if the values pass through the service unchanged. Or save them to a database and see if they are correct there. Just seems like Visual Studio is lying to you

Comment: @bgraham you were right, probably something went wrong with my pc and after restarting it and visual studio, now all seems to work

Comment: Glad you got it figured out! Those are frustrating problems to deal with!

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things that might help.

I think its good practice to make an object to catch the fields like this:

```
public class ManagePermissionsRequest {
    public string usr { get; set; }
    public string gpr { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller add a [FromBody] to the request:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ManagePermissions([FromBody]permissionsRequest) {
   // Your code
}
```

I think that would do the trick. Sometimes though I need to stringify the data in JQuery, so thats worth a try if it still isn't working:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'Post',
            url: '/UserGroups/ManagePermission',
            dataType:'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                'usr': username,
                'grp': groupname
            }),
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })
```

Note: Its good practice to avoid abbreviating variables. I might go with "user" or "username" instead of usr

Comment: None of this seems relevant to the issue the OP describes, where values are received in the Action, but the values are not what he is expecting them to be.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.